# Implementing pipe using shared memory & semaphores

Tags: c, signals, pipe, shared-memory, semaphore

I'm trying to implement a pipe using shared memory and semaphores (it may be that I need signals also, to complete my implementation)

I encountered the algorithmic problem of how to set the semaphores right.

Lets say I already allocated a piece of shared memory for the pipe buffer,
and a piece of shared memory for the pipe's info (such as how much bytes there are in the pipe, etc...)

1. I want to create mutual exclusion (only one reader/writer using the pipe at once)
2. If reader wants to read from an empty pipe, I should block him, till a writer writes something
3. Same thing like '2', but writer who writes to a full pipe

I tried to search for an answer but I didn't find any even though it seems like a common exercise...

I'm aware of a solution called "Bounded buffer problem" or "consumer producer problem"
which is implemented like this:

There are 3 semaphores:
mutex - initialized to 1
full - initialized to 0
empty - initialized to n (whilst n is the number of, lets say "bytes" I have in the pipe)

Consumer's code:

```
wait(full)
wait(mutex)

remove a byte from the pipe

signal(mutex)
signal(empty)
```

Producer's code:

```
wait(empty)
wait(mutex)

add a byte to the pipe

signal(mutex)
signal(full)
```

The problem in this solution (to use as a solution to my problem) is that in a given time, only one byte is read from the pipe, or write into it.

In my problem - Implementing a pipe, I don't know for sure how much bytes a writer will write. If he wants to write 'n' bytes, then he will write it only if there is a place in the pipe, and if not, he will write less then 'n' bytes...

That means that a writer must check how much free space there is in the pipe, before writing into it. This is a problem - because the writer will touch a critical section (the pipe's information) without mutual exclusion..

So I thought about putting this part inside the critical section, but then - if a writer wants to write and the pipe is full - how can I let only one reader inside, and then letting the writer to write more?

I've got confused...

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: SYSV message queues or POSIX message queues are meant for this kind of task.  They are kernel persistent, and simply require send and get calls.

Comment: This looks just fine as is.

Comment: @vonbrand It's not fine as it is (I think), look at the next scenario:
a writer who wants to write 'n' bytes checks how much bytes there are in the pipe, and there is space for 2 bytes more. so the writer will write 2 bytes and will finish (that's how pipe is working isn't it?)..

now: if a writer gets this information, that he can write 2 bytes, then the control goes to a reader, who reads '10 bytes', and the control goes back to the writer which can write 12 bytes, instead of 2 bytes... but he doesn't know that

Comment: You don't "look if there is space, and then write if there is", you ask for space (decreasing the `free` semaphore, if it can' be done, you'll just wait until there is), and write. Look at http://www.greenteapress.com/semaphores, it is certainly possible to handle semaphores that are incremented/decremented not by 1 but by arbitrary amounts.

Comment: @vonbrand , as a reader who wants to read 2 bytes, I need to check if there are 2 bytes to read.. if there is only one byte, then I'll read one bytes and'll go away (like a pipe).. Isn't it ?

I know semaphores can be incremented/decremented not by 1, But this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have so many mutexes or lock them for that amount of time. In single producer/consumer scenario, the producer never needs to worry about the free space reducing (it is the only one that can use up that space), and similarly for the consumer. Therefore your pseudocode should be:

**Producer**

```
while (lock_and_get_free_space() < bytes_to_write)
    wait()
unlock()

write(bytes_to_write)

lock_and_update_free_space()
```

**Consumer**

```
while (lock_and_get_data() < bytes_to_read)
    wait()
unlock()

read(bytes_to_read)

lock_and_update_free_space()
```

Comment: This would lead to deadlock is `bytes_to_write` >= `free_space` && `bytes_to_read` >= `n` - `free_space`, e.g. n == 2, `free_space` = 1, `bytes_to_write` == 2, `bytes_to_read` == 2. Also you seem to be waiting while having a mutex, which is guaranteed to give you deadlock.

Comment: @wich The buffer system should be designed so that you read/write sane amounts of data w.r.t. the buffer size. `wait` in the pseudocode often means "release and wait"; for example see the behaviour of [pthread_cond_wait](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait)

Comment: _you read/write sane amounts of data w.r.t. the buffer size_ This doesn't make any sense, reading or writing n bytes in one go is sane.

Comment: @CongXu can you explain what `lock_and_get_free_space()`, `wait()`, `lock_and_get_data()` and `lock_and_update_free_space()` do? So I'll understand the pseudocode... Thanks!

Comment: @hudac assuming you're using pthreads, `lock_and_get_free_space()` does a `pthread_lock` plus gets the buffer free space (buffer capacity minus buffer size), `wait` is `pthread_cond_wait`, `lock_and_update_free_space()` is a `pthread_lock`, update buffer size (because you just wrote to it), and `pthread_unlock`.